# Center verticaly a paragraph in a div

Tags: css, image, html, center, vertical-alignment

I want to center verticaly a paragraph in a div.
For that, I tried to add an image front my text and I add the css "vertical-align:middle" on it.

The first line of my text is verticaly aligned : it's good, but the second line is under my div.

How can I solve my problem ?

Thks

**[MY JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nSk5r/)**

```
div {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    background:cyan;
    position:absolute;
}

span {
    height:inherit;
    width:inherit;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    background: yellow;
    text-align:center 
}

img {
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:3px;}
}
```

Comment: you tell the image to have a 100% height, as a inline element any following line will start below the 100%, which in your case is below the div.

Comment: It should be noted that there is no paragraph in your fiddle!

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `display:table` css:

```
div {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background:cyan;
    display:table;
}

span {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/nSk5r/2/)

Comment: I need my div has the "display:inline-block"

Comment: @Bonjour, just add an extra div inside then and give that a style of table: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/nSk5r/5/

Comment: @Bonjour, actually you don't need the extra div.  You can just define the proportions on the table-cell and keep your div as inline-block:  http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/nSk5r/6/